# How to configure portlet in liferay 6.1 programmatically?

Tags: liferay, portlet

How to set specific options of different portlets programmatically? For example how to set view in "Web Content Display" portlet to specific JournalArticle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one might be a bit difficult because there will be some discovery involved. First you'll need to figure out which preference key you'd like to over write. The difficult lies that the developer can use any key for example some of Liferay's are `portlet-setup-show-borders`.

But to set a Web Content Display, you can use something like:

```java
PortletPreferences portletSetup =
    PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getLayoutPortletSetup(
        layout, portletId);

portletSetup.setValue("groupId", String.valueOf(layout.getGroupId()));
portletSetup.setValue("articleId", articleId);

portletSetup.store();
```

Comment: Thank ypu for idea. In liferay 6.1 some of the parameters names was changes. "group-id" now is "groupId" and "article-id" is "articleId".

Comment: Thanks @EdGrin, I have updated the answer to reflect the change in 6.1.